# Why does python gstreamer crash without "gobject.threads_init()" at the top of my script?

Tags: python, thread-safety, gstreamer, gobject

I have written a python script to use gstreamer (pygst and gst modules) to calculate replaygain tags, and it was crashing inconsistently with various gobject errors. I found somewhere that you could fix this by putting the following boilerplate at the top of your script:

```
import gobject
gobject.threads_init()
```

I tried it, and it worked. Can anyone explain why these lines are necessary, and why pygst doesn't do this itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because, you can use gobject in a non threading environment. This is not unusual.
When you use gobject in a threading environment, you need to explicitly initialize by calling gobject.threads_init(). This will also ensure that the when "C" functions are called, the GIL is freed.

- [Python, Threads, the GIL, and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934898/python-threads-the-gil-and-c)
- [Explain Python extensions multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825362/explain-python-extensions-multithreading)

Also from the function document :

> The threads_init() function
>   initializes the use of Python
>   threading in the gobject module. This
>   function is different than the
>   gtk.gdk.threads_init() function as
>   that function also initializes the gdk
>   threads.

Basically, you tell gobject module explicitly that you are going to use threading and initialize it accordingly.

Comment: But it seems that the python gstreamer module tries to use threading no matter what, as evidenced by the crashes that occur when I don't call `threads_init()`. So if it always tries to use threading, shouldn't it always initialize it?

Comment: Or to put it more bluntly, why doesn't pygst include this line of code, which is required for it to work without crashing?

Comment: I'd say it's not pygst's job to do that but the application's. If every library/binding did that, it would get done again every time you load one.